# How to show rows with duplicate values first in SQL without grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table like this
I want to fetch all products, but I want to show products with the same PID first (without grouping them)

Sample Table

```
pid product
1   Red
3   Green
2   Blue
4   Violet
3   Magenta
1   Black
```

Expected Results

```
pid product
1   Red
1   Black
3   Green
3   Magenta
2   Blue
4   Violet
```

I tried this  **`ORDER BY pid ASC`**
it partially solves the problem but results appear like this

```
pid product
1   Red
1   Black
2   Blue (comes in between)
3   Green
3   Magenta
4   Violet
```

I want all products with more than one pid to come first sorted from top to bottom.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Especially for this one as `ORDER BY pid` should do exactly what you are wanting. Something feels wrong about your data or it's not clear what you are asking. Sample data and desired results would help a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment I think your `MySQL` version doesn't support windows function so you could use:

```
SELECT
  t.pid,
  t.product,
            ( SELECT COUNT('pid') 
              FROM test_tbl ct 
              WHERE ct.pid = t.pid
            ) as counter
FROM
  test_tbl t
  order by counter desc,pid asc ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> pid   product   counter
> 1      Red        2
> 1      Black      2
> 3      Green      2
> 3      Magenta    2
> 2      Blue       1
> 4      Violet     1
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=126af8cafbd8f7c1c2c10a62aa0db2c4)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pid) cnt
    FROM datatable
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: says Unrecognised statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)
I guess'WITH' is not supported

Comment: @SiddyHacks possibly your `MySQL` version is older than 8+